# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with gridlayoutmanager

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview recieving data from firebase and i want to make last item uploaded to be first item in the list.I'm using GridLayoutManager and want to display a pic with a text, all of this work fine but i want to make them in order like instagram, does any one know something like that ?

**Here is my code**

```
public class ItemsUser extends Fragment {

private View mMainView;
private RecyclerView mUsersList;
private String user_id;

private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ItemRecycleview,UserRecycleView> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private FirebaseListAdapter<ItemRecycleview> firebaseListAdapter;

public ItemsUser() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items_user, container, false);

    mUsersList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_profile);
    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3));

    ProfileUser activity = (ProfileUser) getActivity();
    user_id = activity.getMyData();

    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users_photos").child(user_id);
    mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    return mMainView;
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ItemRecycleview, UserRecycleView>(
            ItemRecycleview.class,
            R.layout.recycleview_item,
            UserRecycleView.class,
            mUserDatabase
    ) {


        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UserRecycleView viewHolder, ItemRecycleview model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setImageName(model.getImageName());
            viewHolder.setImageURL(model.getImageURL(),getContext());

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String key = firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(mUsersList.getChildLayoutPosition(v)).getKey();
                    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageActivity.class);
                    imageIntent.putExtra("imageKey",key);
                    imageIntent.putExtra("user_id",user_id);
                    startActivity(imageIntent);
                }
            });

        }


    };
    mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class UserRecycleView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public UserRecycleView(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

    }
    public void setImageName(String imageName){

        TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView);
        userNameView.setText(imageName);

    }
    public void setImageURL(final String imageURL,final Context ctx){

        final ImageView userImageView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageURL).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(userImageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageURL).into(userImageView);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

**and this is ItemRecyclerview:**

```
public class ItemRecycleview {

public String imageName;
public String imageURL;

public ItemRecycleview(){

}

public ItemRecycleview(String imageName, String imageURL) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
}

public String getImageName() {
    return imageName;
}

public void setImageName(String imageName) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
}

public String getImageURL() {
    return imageURL;
}

public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
}
```

}

Comment: so you fetching an array which is to be set to the list adapter?

Comment: yes , exactly and i want last item uploaded to be the first position . can you understand me !

Comment: did your code have an array loop in which all data is displayed to list view? if yes can you post it here?

Comment: no, this is all the code

Comment: The logic is simple.. Just reverse the array while displaying the result. That is display the array from bottom to top with for loop equals the size of array and every time perform -- instead of ++. Got it?

Comment: @Sam he have not array, Just look at code!

Comment: @MilosLulic i asked if he is fetching array that is to be set in listview, he said yes

Comment: @Sam sorry but i miss understand your first comment, i dont have array

Comment: Oh, Then it is useless. don't try it, check the answer below if it is working?

Comment: @Sam doesn't work cause gridlayoutmanager doesn't support reverseLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey guys i just found the answer :D

all you need to do is to add this method in firebaseRecyclerAdapter

here it's:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ItemRecycleview, UserRecycleView>(
            ItemRecycleview.class,
            R.layout.recycleview_item,
            UserRecycleView.class,
            mUserDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        public ItemRecycleview getItem(int position) {
            return super.getItem(getItemCount() - 1 - position);
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UserRecycleView viewHolder, ItemRecycleview model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setImageName(model.getImageName());
            viewHolder.setImageURL(model.getImageURL(),getContext());

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String key = firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(mUsersList.getChildLayoutPosition(v)).getKey();
                    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageActivity.class);
                    imageIntent.putExtra("imageKey",key);
                    imageIntent.putExtra("user_id",user_id);
                    startActivity(imageIntent);
                }
            });

        }


    };
```

and that will make it done

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using setReverseLayout() method to make first element last in the list

```
GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3);
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
mUsersList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: yes i tried but it shows and error : GridLayoutManager does not support stack from end. Consider using reverse layout

Comment: Should've been a comment